# iOS 9 app support to publish the app in the App Store

Tags: ios, app-store, ios9

I am planning to publish an iPhone app in App store in 2 weeks.
Is it mandatory for the app to work on iOS9 to get it approved by Apple?
Any idea anyone?

Comment: support iOS 9 compulsory to approve??? I would say No

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple never announce that type of news about application must be support on higher version.

By using `iOS` development tool `Xcode` you can set your application deployment target for support lower version. So don't worry at all there is no any restriction to compulsory support iOS9. And iOS9 will be fully release on 16th sep 2015.

Answer (score 1):

As of Feb 1st, 2015, iOS app submissions to Apple's App store must be built with iOS 8 or later.  See: https://developer.apple.com/news/

However, starting on Sep 16th 2015, if not sooner, Apple will be testing iOS app submissions on iOS 9 devices.  Apps will almost certainly be rejected if they do not run on these iOS 9 devices.

However many apps built with older SDKs, such as iOS 8, will run on iOS 9 devices. So, if you don't build your app using Xcode 7 (or later) and iOS 9 (or newer) then you should at least test on the latest GM or release iOS version.

Comment: This is the best answer, and I have empirical evidence of its validity: "We discovered one or more bugs in your app when reviewed on iPad running iOS 9 and iPhone running iOS 9 on both Wi-Fi and cellular networks". The app has been around for a while and works fine on iOS8, this was just an update.

Answer (score 0):

One shouldn't be bother about running the app on higher versions. iOS9 will fully support the apps running on previous versions. There is no question of rejection for this.

Comment: How can you tell? There have been quite many cases where apps break on new iOS versions. So why is iOS 9 an exception?

Comment: Breaking of app  and non-compatibility  are the two different things. If it is not compatible it won't be installed at all.

Comment: So you claim that an application that crashes is compatible with iOS 9, just because it installs? Interesting definition. And you claim iOS9 will fully support the apps. So causing them to crash would still be "fully support"?

Comment: Well I have an app that runs through from iOS6 to iOS8.4. Doesn't have as such problem.

Comment: You didn't answer the question. As I said, many apps break so you can't claim it to fully support any app that runs on an older version.

Comment: There is no provision that you could stop your app installing on higher versions. That decides the compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

At Sep 14th my app was rejected because it doesn't work properly at ios9. Before the official announcement.